# Apostrophe in DataView RowFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataView that I'm trying to filter based on a dynamic string:

```
dv.RowFilter = "ContentTitle = '" + titleFilter + "'";
```

In some cases, `titleFilter` contains an apostrophe, which is closing out the filter query and causing an error.

Is there a way I can escape that character? I can't replace it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply double the apostrophe (a.k.a. quote) inside the `titleFilter` string with

```
dv.RowFilter = "ContentTitle = '" + titleFilter.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```