# How to use multiple BindingSource Filters to conduct a search using 2 different textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I've been googling for several hours now trying to come up with a way around this. When I run the program, it works but doesn't filter both values, it just uses the one which is no good to me. I have come across several stack overflow threads but none of them quite meet my criteria.

Is there a way that these can be used together in order to help the user narrow down the search for a record?

```
Private Sub Searchbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Searchbtn.Click


    Me.MainDBBindingSource3.Filter = "Surname ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

    Me.MainDBBindingSource3.Filter = "DOB ='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Filter = "Foo = 'xyz' AND Bar = 'abc'"`

Comment: Filter = "Surname = 'textbox1.text' AND DOB = 'textbox2.text'" like this?

Comment: Not quite.  Just combine your two statements with that AND.  Is DOB really a string?

Comment: Me.MainDBBindingSource3.Filter = "Surname ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'" And "DOB ='" & TextBox2.Text & "'" OK, this is what I have so far, is this correct? also, DOB is a string.. is that not right?

Comment: Change `"'" And "DOB` to `"' And DOB`  Otherwise, try it out and you tell us if it works or not.

Comment: ah, thank you. that works but I can't search using just surname. It will only work if I type the DOB. Any ideas? Thanks @LarsTech

Comment: Then you need an if block in your code.  `If TextBox2.Text = "" Then` if you only have a filter for surname, else include the DOB part.

Comment: I'm new to this. I understand what an IF statement is but have no clue how to format it..? Is there any chance you could give me an example? @LarsTech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, this is how you could format your filter:

```
If TextBox2.Text = String.Empty Then
  Me.MainDBBindingSource3.Filter = "Surname ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
Else
  Me.MainDBBindingSource3.Filter = "Surname ='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND DOB ='" & _
                                   TextBox2.Text & "'"
End If
```

Also, see [How to properly escape SQL when using BindingSource's Filter property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699724/719186) and [Apostrophe in DataView RowFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16362464/719186)